# What are the ways of hiding Shell script commands in command line due to command failure or bad input file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I am creating a bash script for automating command line operations. I have observed that if I enter incorrect password or the input file is parsed incorrectly, the next commands from script are visible in command line. 
I want to hide those commands from my script from appearing to end user. What are the ways of doing that ?

Comment: How are you running the script if the commands are _visible on the command line_, and what do you mean by _hiding_?  Could you give an example?

Comment: It's not normal for commands in a script to be printed (except as part of error messages indicating what command had an error). So the first question is: why are they getting printed? We'd need more details (i.e. the script, and exactly what's getting printed) to have an idea what's causing it and how to avoid it.

Comment: I will share what I can. I'm running a script to ssh into machines in local machines having zookeeper. The script uses reference from multiple files to implement admin services on clusters. There was a file with bad parsing, after taking those incorrect inputs the commands executed after are shown in command line.
Example:{'
while read -r line
        do
        sshpass -p 'YourPassword' ssh user@host
        echo "this task performed"
         done< filename
'}
On CMD where I run the file. If the input file has bad parsing, I see.
> ./run_bash_zk.sh
>echo "this task performed"

Comment: Ideally, I shouldn't see any bash code from my script file in the Unix command.

Comment: Code in comments is hardly ever readable. Please [edit] the question. Even if you fail at formatting, we will be able to make it readable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the next command only happens when the first command succeeds, add && between two commands.

```
command 1 && command2
```

or you can check the result of first command by a IF statement:

```
if [ $? -ne 0 ];then
 exit 1;
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But by using "&&" we're executing next command only when both of previous are successful. This isn't an elegant for multi line commands. Is there any way to mask commands from the bash script ever appearing into central command ? Actually I got an idea from your approach, I can just exit the shell after bad parse. I would still prefer an alternate solution this exit approach.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your scripts?